# visual studio 2010 setup project - removing registry

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, registry

I have 2 msi files that I run silently one after the other from win forms application (master installer for that matter). Both of them configured to write to registry to same location,
for example:

```
HKLM\Software\MyProduct\MSI1
HKLM\Software\MyProduct\MSI2
```

Now, I run uninstall in reverse order and when uninstall done, MSI1 removed from registry, but MSI2 is stuck there... Is there anything can be done about that without custom action or coding?

Comment: Each package should remove it's own registry entries during uninstall. Did you try creating a verbose uninstall log to see why the entries are not removed? http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log/

Comment: Disallowing uninstallation of component: {129E4711-04E2-61E4-77C2-F6B6D234AFA7} since another client exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your registry entries use the same component as another product installed on the machine. For example, you copied the setup project of an existing product and used the copy to create an MSI for a different product.

To avoid it, you need to make sure that each MSI uses unique [component names and GUIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's not easy in Visual Studio setup projects. You can try editing the project file. If it doesn't work, it's better to start from scratch with a new setup project.

Comment: I don't understand the concept of component name, sorry. Those 2 projects created not copied and both have different names and different product code... Isn't that enough? Also, if there is component guid, how do I change it? Where do I find it? I do use VS2010. Thanks

Comment: I did mention that it's not easy in Visual Studio :). It doesn't allow direct access to components. Did you read the article I linked? Somehow, another MSI (the other client) is referencing your component. This is why Windows Installer doesn't remove it. If it's not another product, perhaps it's an older version of your MSI. Did you test on a clean machine?

Comment: Yes, of course I read the article :) Thanks a lot for your answer. Ill try to workaround with post build script or something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found problem in VS2010 (Big Thanks to Cosmin Pirvu) and just will go on and put here the 2 solution options I see so far. But first, the problem:

As I mentioned I have 2 entries:
HKLM\Software\MyProduct\MSI1
HKLM\Software\MyProduct\MSI2

But in code, they look the same because MSI1 and MSI2 being "place holders":
HKLM\Software\MyProduct[ProductName]

So, the name is identical and properties identical this is why we get same component id for both!

Two things (as far as i see) you can do:

1. Instead of [ProductName] enter actual product name (hard coded)
2. (What I did is) In registry entry property, in condition field, enter meaningless string (make it really meaningless, so it wont meat reasonable condition, i used guid with leading __).

Thanks for all answers